# Laravel blade asset for image variable in a loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This is for a small school assignment.

We are trying to create and deploy a search website of local cricket players.
I have everything running locally the only thing is I need to use is asset on my images to get them to deploy properly.

currently I have in my local

```
<img src="/images/{{$player['image']}}" class="playerimg">
```

I have tried concatenating it but to no avail.
The reason I have a variable $player is because we are pulling data from two tables and looping around the array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Edit: Solved Thank you all for your help ! code below

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/'.$player['image']) }}" class="playerimg">
```

Comment: In case if your image is in uploads, or storage folder use `{{ url('images/'.$player['image']) }}`

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel - Helpers: asset()**
https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-asset

```php
<img src="{{ asset('images/'.$player['image']) }}" class="playerimg">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to display the image.

I'm assuming index.php in public folder.

### [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) Generates a URL to an application asset [(code)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L210)

- Use for files that are directly served such as CSS, images, javascript.
- Only accepts a direct path.

  ```
  {{ asset('images/'.$player['image']) }}
  // http://www.example.com/public/images/abc.png
  ```

If you stored your image in storage folder then,

```
<img src="{{ storage_path('images/'.$player['image']) }}">
```

Make sure config.php should be configured properly for `storage_path`.